# Qt file resize behaves weirdly in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, file

Here is my code snippet

```
QFile temfile(fileUrl);
if(temfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) == false)
{
    qDebug()<<"Unable to create file!";
    return;
}
if(temfile.resize(5073741824) == false)  // 5GB
{
    qDebug()<<"Insufficient disk space!";
    return;
}
temfile.close();
```

Now on Windows, if the NTFS filesystem has less than 5GB disk space, it displays

```
Insufficient disk space!
```

But on Linux (Ubuntu 12.10) the file is resized even if there is less space. On right click properties file size is even displayed as 5GB but it is not accounted for somehow. I can create as many 5GB files as I want due to which above code check fails.

When I start writing into file (suppose 200MB) only then the size is accounted for 200MB but displayed as 5GB.

Is there any solution for this? I want this to behave as it behaves on Windows.

**Edit: So as per peppe's answer here is the working code:**

```
    QFile temfile(fileUrl);
    if(temfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) == false)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Unable to create file!";
        return;
    }
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    if(fallocate(temfile.handle(), 0, 0, 5073741824) < 0)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Insufficient disk space!";
        return;
    }

#else
    if(temfile.resize(5073741824) == false)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Insufficient disk space!";
        return;
    }
#endif
    temfile.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) on the file descriptor wrapped by that QFile object, in order to make the kernel actually allocate the space on disk.

What's happening here is that you're allocating a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) -- a file filled of NUL bytes, whose allocation gets optimized by your file system into a simple "keep track of the advertised size of the file".

<sub>As a side note: you shouldn't be using such 64 bit integer literals, but wrapping them into `Q_INT64_C` instead.</sub>